# Trying to add a "add to wishlist button" in my Django web application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to add an "add to wishlist" button to my page that lists books.
When a user presses the button, it will add the isbn (pk of the books) along with the user id into the wishlist table.
For some reason, it's not adding them into my database when I press the button. There are no errors shown so i don't know what's the problem.

Here's my code

```
#views.py
class wishlistView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'TextSearch/wishlist.html'

    def post(self, request, pk):
        isbn = self.request.POST.get('isbn')
        current_user = request.user
        book = wishlist(userid_id = current_user.id, ISBN_id = isbn)
        book.save()
        return
```

my HTML code

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{book.pk}}" name="isbn">
    <a href="{% url 'TextSearch:wishlist' book.pk %}" >Add To WishList</a>
    </form>
   {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'User:RegisterView'  %}"  >Add To WishList</a>
   {% endif %}
```

my table

```
#models.py
class wishlist (models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ISBN = models.ForeignKey(books, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Thank You in advance, I'm new to Django.

Comment: Are you sure `book.pk` is actually set in form hidden input?

Comment: @Charnel  how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- issue is fixed --
it was just a HTML mistake here's the updated code

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'TextSearch:wishlist' book.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{book.pk}}" name="isbn">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to wishlist">
    </form>
   {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'User:RegisterView'  %}"  >Add To WishList</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this method

MY MODEL:

```
class UserWishlist(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)
products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

than in my view:

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
obj, created = UserWishlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
if product in obj.products.all():
    obj.products.remove(product)
else:
    obj.products.add(product)
    return JsonResponse({'msg':'Item added to wishlist!'})
```

much easier IMO and helps in toggling too